# How could I "turn off" a stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I am creating a website for a University assignment and we have to concentrate on the accessability functions. I have successfully managed to use resize text buttons but am looking for a way to turn off a css file via a button or link.

I have scoured the net and cannot seem to find very much, I found a good website that had the button I am looking for so hit F12 but it would not display the javascript for it.

Ideally I would like to achieve it without the use of javascript but if there is no other way then I am open to any help that I can get.

I am sorry if this is a simple question but I really did look hard for an answer but to no avail, I am only a first year student so have a long way to go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it server side when the user clicks on a "special" link, your server side code simply "skips" the stylesheets elements.

Comment: This method is probably best because the browser will have less to parse.

Comment: @Tyler Crompton: it's not about being "lighter" on the browser, but with accessibility. If you have to disable the CSSs (a very particular situation, maybe some mpaired user with a special browser?) you can't assume the browser is able to handle  JavaScript.

Comment: The technical term is `styleswitcher` I think (if you google it, you'll have to add `server side` in order to avoid JS solutions).

Comment: @kappa, I never mentioned JavaScript. However, seeing as he is a first-year college student doing this for an assignment, my guess is that he will be incapable of server-side scripting. So that puts him in a pickle.

Comment: @Tyler Crompton: what where you talking about then? I'm serious about it, I wrote JavaScript because I didn't think of what else could be "heavy" on the browser, so I'm curious. oO"

Comment: @kappa: If you set a variable in PHP, for example, you can use the variable in an if statement to determine whether or not a style sheet is sent to the browser. Therefore, the browser will be ignorant to anything ever being there and not have to worry about parsing CSS that won't even be used.

Comment: @Tyler: Oh, I see now, I've read your comment the other way roud, I thought you said this way was lighter on the browser than the other relying ont the browser to disable the stylesheets (like the JS solutions posted here). oO

Answer (score 38):

This should work

```
for ( i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    void(document.styleSheets.item(i).disabled=true);
}
```

Comment: may I please have your permission to use it? If you agree I shall put you 'agreeing' into my report.

Comment: @Phil: Everything posted here is under the Creative Commons "Attribute" licence (see the botom of the page) so you don't have to ask for permission. :)

Comment: @JohnGiotta why are you using `void()` here?

Comment: @xaviervalarino it was so long ago, I don't recall, but void will just terminate the returned boolean.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a good way to do it quickly from javascript:

1. Precede all of your CSS rules with the tag `body.enabled`:

   ```
   body.enabled p {
   }

   body.enabled #Myselector {
   }
   ...
   ```
2. Declare your markup as such:

   ```
   ...
   <body class="enabled">
       ...
   </body>
   ...
   ```
3. In your JavaScript, when you want to disable CSS, remove the class `"enabled"` from the `<body>` and switch it with something else (say, "disabled"). Use whatever methodology you see fit to do this (jQuery would make this easy, but it can be done without)

You're not really disabling CSS using this, you're just making it so that none of it applies. From a user's standpoint, they likely won't know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to mimick every feature already designed in browsers (T+, T-, no CSS)? Were you asked to make an accessible website or specifically to implement accessibility features? I understand this is an assignment but that's quite a waste of time IMHO, a time that would be better spent on implementation of WCAG 2.0 recommendation. (I use the ["Accessiweb" methodology](http://www.braillenet.org/accessibilite/referentiel-aw21-en/index.php) a lot).

My first idea was to deconstruct existing CSS like [Universal IE6](https://code.google.com/p/universal-ie6-css/) does for IE6 (you just have to remove the conditional comments and aim to every browser) but @kappa solution seems better as in both cases you must have access to source code.